# Allow second form to change the visibly of a picturebox on form 1?

Tags: c#

Form1: I have set the modifiers to public for the image -> Home_picturebox1

Form2:

```
    public Form1 Firstform = new Form1(); // This is above the following code

    private void PS3IP_Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //PS3.ConnectTarget(PS3IP_Textbox1.Text); // Update the IP
        Firstform.Home_picturebox1.Show();
        //this.Close();
    }
```

It compiles fine but the image isn't shown once the event has been called?

Any ideas? ://

Answer (score 2):

`new Form1` does exactly what it says, creates a new instance of Form1, you need to pass a reference to your original form, one way of doing this is in the constructor.

```
private Form1 FirstForm;
public Form2(Form1 myForm)
{
    FirstForm = myForm;
}
```

Comment: I get this: 'PS3_RTM_CP.Form1' is a type but is used like a variable'

Comment: @user3733598 - how are you calling it?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

When you declare

```
public Form1 Firstform = new Form1();
```

It is actually creating a **new** form object.

**Solution:**

You need to send the object of `Form1` to `Form2` as a parameter and then change the visibility of `Home_picturebox1`.

In Form1:

```
private void btnGoToForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PS3IP obj= new PS3IP(this);
    obj.Show();
}
```

In Form2:

```
public Form1 Firstform;
public PS3IP(Form1 ParentForm)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     FirstForm=ParentForm;
} 
private void PS3IP_Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //PS3.ConnectTarget(PS3IP_Textbox1.Text); // Update the IP
    Firstform.Home_picturebox1.Show();
    //this.Close();
}
```

Comment: This just gives me the error: "The name 'This' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: Gives me these: http://i.gyazo.com/2dee6201581b10d7b5828e7c89bf694c.png - Thanks for the help <3

Comment: What is the name of Form2?

Comment: PS3IP.cs <- That is my second form.

Comment: @user3733598: Then use it instead of 'Form2' as shown in my answer.

Comment: I have replaced every Form2 with my form 2's name but I still receive the two errors shown in the chat. It's really that overall important so I wouldn't worry but I appreciate the help and time :)

Comment: @user3733598: That is a constructor. We are overloading the constructor here. What is the error now?

Comment: Solved the errors and it compiles but upon execution, I get this. http://i.gyazo.com/b0be948532003df40b221a9eb740c3af.png

Comment: @user3733598: Use `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor. See in my answer. That will solve your problem.

Comment: still recieve the same issue. Don't worry i'll do an alternative method of design but thank you for your time! <33

Comment: @user3733598: Feel free to accept the answer. If you don't know how to accept an answer, please [**read this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You not reference the current instance of form1 but you create a new one, try:

```
   Form1 form1;
    public Form6(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1=form1;
    }

private void PS3IP_Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form1.Home_picturebox1.Show();
        //this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: This gives me the error: 'NullReferenceException was unhandled - Object reerence not set to an instance of an object'.